# Gitosis not accepting numbers in hostname

Tags: linux, git, ssh

My computer's host name is set to '37MeanMachine', and my key is like:

`ssh-rsa AA.....== thirtySeven@37MeanMachine`

The problem is that, when I try to initialize gitosis with this key, I get the error:

`gitosis.init.InsecureSSHKeyUsername: Username contains not allowed characters: 'thirtySeven@37MeanMachine'`

When I changed my key to

`ssh-rsa AA.....== thirtySeven@MeanMachine`

i.e. I removed '37' from my hostname in the ssh-key, it ran perfectly fine and the key initialized. AFAIK, it is completely valid for a hostname to have numbers, why am I having a problem in my case? And what is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hostname should not start with a digit.

See https://www.poweradmin.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/DNS-hostnames